# GNU Readline: How to pass data to a completion function without using global variables?

Tags: c, readline

I have a pointer to a structure that is dynamically changed by input during the program execution. This pointer is used to generate options.

Basically, I have...

```
ret = rl_completion_matches(string, rl_options_generator_string);
```

How can I pass this pointer to `rl_options_generator_string(const char *string, int state)` without using global variables? Is there a way?

Comment: Presumably, 'int state', has something to do with it, though I would be happier if it was a void*.

Comment: Yes, @MartinJames. I agree with you. It will help us anad it won't affect the function purpose.